# .then() em Async/Await

Tags: javascript, assincronismo, async-await

Como eu transformaria a seguinte função utilizando async/await?

```
const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimetout(resolve, 1000);

function umPorSegundo() {
   delay().then(() => {
      console.log('1s');

      delay().then(() => {
         console.log('2s');

         delay().then(() => {
            console.log('3s');
         });
      });
   });
}

umPorSegundo();
```

Sei que seria algo assim:

```
const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

async function umPorSegundo(){
    console.log(await delay());
    console.log(await delay());
    console.log(await delay());
}

umPorSegundo();
```

Porém, não sei como passo uma string diferente a cada await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás quase lá! O que falta é teres uma função que se chama a si própria, e depois passar um contador para ir incrementando os valores...

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const delay = (str) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(str), 1000));

async function umPorSegundo(nr = 0) {
  const segundos = await delay(nr) + 's';
  console.log(segundos);
  return umPorSegundo(nr + 1);
}

umPorSegundo();
```

Comment: Isso! Era isso que eu precisava mesmo, muito obrigado!